# What does the [embedded] tag on AskUbuntu mean?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

[embedded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/embedded) has questions about embedded systems, about audio embedded in a PDF, and about embedding a terminal in the desktop, as well as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65500/can-i-ssh-via-usb) about a tablet, which might be considered an embedded system by some.

What does this tag mean?

I ask because I've tried to follow questions about electronics on several sites across the network via [this feed](http://stackexchange.com/filters/12100/electronics-questions-not-on-ee), should AskUbuntu's [embedded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/embedded) tag be included in this feed?

Comment: Kevin, you can try following the [tag:embedded-system] tag now...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest we do away with this tag, which has been used ambiguously.

It has been used to describe embedding audio file in PDF, embedding lyrics in music tracks, Gedit embedded terminals to embedding terminals in Nautilus browser.

As you can see, there is no clear usage of this tag and is only used vaguely.

Please kill this tag either by manual retagging or mod hammering.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed: too vague, ambiguous, overbroad, etc. (writing some legalese atm ;)

Tag has been eradicated; and replaced where appropriate; specifically with [embedded-system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/embedded-system) where tablets, Pandaboards, etc. are concerned. Added a brief tag-wiki, will expand when I have the chance.